# Memory issue? How to get the desired output Efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with 10 million rows as

ID    Speed

AB         34

AB         45

BC         60

BC         32

BC         40

EF         90

Suppose I want to create a third column of Acceleration which takes either 0(deceleration) or 1(acceleration) on ID level.

In total I have more than 2000 unique ID's.

I tried this

```py
for id in df['ID'].unique() :
    df.loc[df['ID'] == id,'speed']
    df['acceleration'] = df['speed'].apply(accl)
```

My accl function is as follows

```py
def accl(a):
   for i in range(1,len(a))    :
        if a[i] > a[i-1]:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

After running the loop I am getting Memory issue.

How to solve this efficiently ? Any technique ? How to solve this using Numpy array if that's the solution?

Remember : I need the data on ID level so just succesive i+ 1 > i on df['speed'] will not work for getting Acceleration column.

Comment: Explain the calculation, not just paste your code.